# Instability in STM32F4 USB connection

Tags: microcontroller, usb, stm32f4

I use a ***STM32F407ZET6*** microcontroller. I make the connection and data transmission from the microcontroller to the computer through a ***USB*** network. I am currently facing some disconnection issues. Sometimes the USB connects and then disconnects. The circuit I use is below. Reading in some places I realized that if I took out the resistors ***R345*** and ***R346*** could perform better. By removing the resistors the connection has improved, but with some cables the continuous error (seems to be with the line impedance). I already tested on USB 2.0 and 3.0 ports and the error happens in both cases. The firmware I use for USB connection is provided by ST itself so I think it is correct. Could anyone tell me if the circuit below is correct or what could I do to stop disconnecting the USB?

[image]

Comment: You're probably going to need to post your circuit board layout from the connector to the micro also.

Comment: Good luck.. The problem could be hardware, or the usb descriptor on the device side, or the actual code on the device side, or something screwy on the computer side.  I find USB tough to debug, though I imagine it's easier with pro gear.

Comment: The R345 and 346 resistors are termination resistors - these are pretty much required for maximum cable length (3m to 5m). 
I had to use a scope (and PulseView to analyse the USB data) in order to find a softwer error that caused the PC to trigger an USB reset.

Comment: What do you mean "through a USB network"? Are you using standard certified USB cables for this "network", or something else? Also, which mode do you use, HS or FS?

Comment: Ali Chen I'm using a standard USB cable. Use FS mode, example: static int8_t CDC_Init_FS (void)